# TextView scrolling is resetting when I update a different TextView from the same ListView row

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewholder

I have a listview and for a specific item I'm refreshing the remaining time every second.
It works fine, but I'm having a small bug.
Whenever I call

```
duration.setText(newRemainingValue);
```

to update the value, another textView from the same row is impacted.
This other textVewi displays a scolling text

```
title.setSelected(true);
title.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

and whenever I change the 1st textView value, the second one resets the scrolling and starts scrolling from the beginning. It looks like this issue is only present when I do this in a ListView

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: could you post your code

Comment: I posted the useful code from the adapter. Basically I just want to know if it's an Android bug and if there's a workaround for this issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like the textviews are set to wrap_content.  That will trigger a layout pass whenever the text is changed.  Try using match_parent or setting the width and height to a fixed value, so that changing the text will not trigger a layout pass

Comment: You're totally right ! Setting a fixed width for the TextView I'm updating fixed the issue. Thanks a lot !
Is there by any chance another way to prevent this from happening if I keep a wrap_content width ? Maybe by subclassing TextView and overriding some function ?

Comment: This is realy helpful. You saved my life. Thank you.

Comment: Wow this fixed a textview i have on a fragment in a tab too.  I used the textview for diagnostics for an asynchronous https post the uithread update cut off the last part of the string.
Really a great solution.